# Adding Substring to Input

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add coordinates to a input text after trimming characters from each end of the `string`. But for some reason my trimming part isn't working. Can anyone help me out here? I'd really appreciate it.

Here's my code:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="latlng" onload="getFinal()">

<script>
function getFinal(){
var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
consolelog(input);
var last = (input.length)-1;
var final = input.substring(1,last);
document.getElementById('final').value = final;
}
</script>

<input type='hidden' id='final'>
```

::: EDIT :::

I've tried simplifying things because the value that needs to be trimmed is in the rest of the code. But for some reason, when I use the code below, it still won't put the value in the text box.

```
var final = pos.substring(1,(pos.length)-1);
  document.getElementById("final").value = final;
```

Now I'm getting the error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at :4:44

Comment: Does the console display an error for `consolelog`?

Comment: Nope. Nothing. @DavidSherret

Comment: One simple thing is you forgot the . in console.log. Please tell me what appears in the console when you use this modified function. function getFinal(){
var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
console.log(input);
var last = (input.length)-1;
console.log(last);
var final = input.substring(1,last);
console.log(final);
document.getElementById('final').value = final;
}

Comment: I do not believe that `onload` event is supported for `<inout type="hidden">` HTML element.

Comment: @PM77-1 that's what it is: http://jsfiddle.net/3c10w0qe/

Comment: @PM77-1 ... and even if it would be, the function is defined afterwards and the target element is not yet loaded. I would put that in a `document.ready` state

Comment: @DavidSherret ... and your point is? Are you saying that this Fiddle is working?

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm saying that's what the problem is—that you are correct (that the onload event isn't being called)

Comment: Though [currently published HTML5 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#handler-onload) seemingly insist that `onload` should be supported on all HTML elements.

Comment: You have to realize that `onLoad()` even executes only once after elements has been appeared. That's probably the wrong event you're handing. You need `onkeyup` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

OnLoad should not work for input. You better write as a simple javascript block

```
    <input type="hidden" id="latlng" onload="getFinal()" />
    <input type='hidden' id='final' />
    <script>
    var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
    consolelog(input);
    var last = (input.length)-1;
    var final = input.substring(1,last);
    document.getElementById('final').value = final;
    </script>
```

Comment: To make it work, maybe you need to place that inside `window.load = function(){.. here ..}`?

Comment: This is the error that I'm getting in console:

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at <anonymous>:4:44`

Comment: What is latlang? Can you give full HTML?